# Sacar Primer registro completo y último de una tabla en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

quería saber como sacar de una tabla en mysql, el primer y el último registro, en una misma consulta, es decir.

**Tengo esta consulta :**

```
SELECT idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) as date, max(readValue) as readValue from ld_reads 
where idCounter = 10570 and date >= '2021-03-16' and date <= '2021-08-04' 
group by idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) 
order by date;
```

**Tengo de resultado de consulta esto:**

```
 idCounter  date        readValue
    10570   2021-03-18  2307
    10570   2021-03-19  2308
    10570   2021-03-20  2312
    10570   2021-03-21  2316
    10570   2021-03-22  2318
    10570   2021-03-23  2321
    10570   2021-03-24  2323
    10570   2021-03-25  2326
    10570   2021-03-26  2328
    10570   2021-03-27  2332
```

Pues yo lo que quiero es sacar únicamente el primer registro completo y el último, de manera
que solo me saque algo así:

```
 idCounter  date        readValue
    10570   2021-03-18  2307
    10570   2021-03-27  2332
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735395/how-to-find-first-and-last-record-from-mysql-table/15166901) tomado de otra pregunta en Stackoverflow.

```sql
SELECT 
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column LIMIT 1) as 'first',
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE [condition] ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last'
```

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo JOIN con una vista que regrese las fechas mínima y máxima:

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM ld_reads r
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT idCounter
                      , min(date) fechaMin
                      , max(date) fechaMax
                   FROM ld_reads
                   WHERE idCounter = 10570
                     AND date between '2021-03-16' and '2021-08-04'
               ) t
      ON    r.idCounter = t.idCounter
        AND r.date in (fechaMin, fechaMax)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) as date, max(readValue) as readValue 
 from ld_reads 
 where idCounter = 10570 and date >= '2021-03-16' and date <= '2021-08-04' 
 group by idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) 
 order by date
 limit 1)
 union 
 (SELECT idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) as date, max(readValue) as readValue 
  from ld_reads 
  where idCounter = 10570 and date >= '2021-03-16' and date <= '2021-08-04' 
  group by idCounter, substr(date, 1, 10) 
  order by desc date
  limit 1)
```

Puedes usar el **operdor de conjunto union**, el cual te permite unir dos consultas como si se tratase de una sola consulta.

Aqui por ejemplo en la primera consulta ordenamos los registros **ascendentemente** y obtenemos el primero, posteriormente en la segunda consulta ordenamos **descendentemente** y obtenemos el primer registro(que en este caso seria el ultimo).

Para usar el **operador union** debes tener en cuenta que ambas consultas deben devolver la misma cantidad de campos y deben tener el mismo tipo.